# ListBox does not display result

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox

/*my problem listbox doesn't show result when i push 'view all' button , but textbox shows but not in iteration version , how can i  fix it?*/

```
from tkinter import * 
import bk
window=Tk()
canvas1 =Canvas(window, width = 500, height = 250)
canvas1.pack()

def view_command():
    for row in  bk.view():
        list1.insert(END , row)


view_all=Button(window ,text='View all', width=20 ,command=view_command)
canvas1.create_window(410 , 76,window=view_all)

list1=Listbox(window , height=10, width=100)
canvas1.create_window(0 , 150, window=list1)

window.mainloop()
```

`#here my bk.py file:`

```
import psycopg2
import csv

def view():
    conn=psycopg2.connect("dbname=books user=postgres password=solmaz123 host=localhost port=13545")
    cur=conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM BOOKS")
    rows=cur.fetchall()
    conn.close()
    return rows
```

Comment: What exactly is your reason of using canvas? The `Listbox` does't show anything because the canvas doesn't get updated.

Comment: Left part of the `list1` is out of the canvas viewable area because it has a large width (100 characters).  So the records inserted may not be seen.  Try making the width of the listbox smaller, like 40 and set `anchor="w"` in `create_window(...)`.